# Split String Array in Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, arrays

Let's say I have a String[] that looks like this:

```
private String[] motherOfStrings = {
  "stringA",
  "stringB",
  "stringC",
  "stringD",
  "stringE",
}
```

Can I split it into multiple String[] like these?

```
private String[] childOfString1 = {
  "stringA",
  "stringB",
  "stringC",
}

private String[] childOfString2 = {
  "stringD",
  "stringE",
}
```

Thanks guys :)

*p.s., i did some search but most of the guides (if not all) are about splitting String[] into Strings, not another String[]. Is this even possible?*

Comment: I added more details on the original post :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `split()` method for every string in your array.

```
String stringByWhichYouWantToSplit = "C";
String[][] splittedStrings = new String[motherOfStrings][];
for(int i = 0; i < motherOfStrings.length; i++)
    splittedStrings[i] = motherOfStrings.split(stringByWhichYouWantToSplit);
```

...if you want to split your strings by `"C"` ...

**EDIT:**

Now, when you edited question I see what you want. You have to create two arrays and copy into them strings from `motherOfStrings`. You can use [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through array and split each `String` into `String[]` or better maintain a `List<String>`